# Why 2 sets of cantillation marks for the 10 commandments?

Tags: torah-reading, aseres-hadibros

There are two sets of ta'amim for the Aseres Hadibros.  (We read in the synagogue using Taamei Elyon.)  But the ta'amim are supposed to be an aid to understanding.  So, what differences in understanding do the two sets of ta'amim provide?

Comment: Who said they provide any differences in understanding? You jump from one quesiton in your title to another in the body

Comment: Note some use Taam Tachton in some synagogue readings.

Comment: https://hefkervelt.blogspot.com/2023/02/the-difference-between-and-why-we-stand.html

Comment: One is the Western, the other is the Eastern tradition.